# Remove commas from number data in salesforce before performing a postgres query

Tags: postgresql

I have a value in salesforce that we store in another database. The value in Salesforce has commas. I have to delete the commas and then place the new number in postgres before performing a query. Is there a way to make this less steps?
Example: SF Number = 1,234,567
1) Paste in Postgres
2) Remove commas manually
3) Run Query

The number can be 4,5,6 or 7 digits long so substr doesn't work consistently

The perfect format at the end should look like --- select * from customers where id=1234567

Answer (score 0):

```
postgres=# select REGEXP_REPLACE('1,234,567', ',', '', 'g');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 1234567
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

Comment: `select translate('1,234,567', ',', '');` should be faster